# how do I call a .php file from another .php file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to call another php file with parameters from another php file.
Below is my code.

```
echo '<a href="RentalPayRecpt.php?id=$RentalId&customer=$CustomerName" target="_blank"></a>';
```

It is not working.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Anyway "not working" tell us exactly nothing about your problem. What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: the called file does not run i.e the RentalPayRecpt.php does not run

Comment: You’ve created an HTML link, you would have to click on it to hit the other PHP file.

Comment: How can I get it to run without clicking on a link?

Comment: You mean you want to call it immediately, without user interaction? Maybe use cURL or file_get_contents if you want to call it via HTTP. But if it's on the same server then you should maybe think about the design so you don't have to pass the query string variables to it, make it more just like a function call. There are various ways, it's hard to give specific advice without any more context

Comment: I am saving payment details and want the receipt t print immediately the details are saved without user interaction.

Comment: Ok well try one of those suggestions then

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code with:

```
echo   '<script> window.open("RentalPayRecpt.php?id='.$RentalId.'&customer='.$CustomerName.'")</script>';
```

If you don't want to open a new window, use window.location.href="url" instead.

Comment: I've test it and It works fine. What is the problem? Isn't new window  opening? You can't get  parameters from url? I've edit the answer for resolve some problem with get parameters. If it still don't works  you have other errors in your code, so you need to share more code with us.